# Rotate snapping to new degree, not smoothly with ease transition

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, rotation

I have quite a complex problem so any help here would be hugely appreciated. Basically, I have a set of images that need rotating.

My actual rotate script works fine (below) however, it's supposed to rotate smoothly and it doesn't, it snaps into position. I'm asking this question on StackOverflow to try and find out why it's snapping, and not rotating smoothly.

I'm using Google Chrome as my browser.

CSS:

```
.marker {
  transition: ease 5s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 5s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function setBearings() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var bearing = markers[i][BEARING];
    var service = markers[i][SERVICE];
    var reg = markers[i][REGISTRATION];

    if (bearing != -1) {
      $(".marker.id-" + reg).css({
        'transform':'rotate('+bearing+'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+bearing+'deg)',
        '-moz-transform':'rotate('+bearing+'deg)',
        '-o-transform':'rotate('+bearing+'deg)',
        '-ms-transform':'rotate('+bearing+'deg)'
      });
    }
  }
}

function updateInfoBoxes() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var googleMarker = getMarkerObject(markers[i][REGISTRATION]);

    actualMarkers[i] = document.createElement("div");
    actualMarkers[i].className = "box";
    actualMarkers[i].addEventListener("click", createHandler(i), false);

    if (markers[i][BEARING] == -1) {
      actualMarkers[i].innerHTML = '<div class="service">' + markers[i][SERVICE] + '</div><img class="marker id-' + markers[i][REGISTRATION] + '" src="images/static.png" />';
    } else {
      actualMarkers[i].innerHTML = '<div class="service">' + markers[i][SERVICE] + '</div><img class="marker id-' + markers[i][REGISTRATION] + '" src="images/dynamic.png" />';
    }

    if (infoBoxes[i])
      infoBoxes[i].setContent(actualMarkers[i]);

    infoBoxes[i] = new InfoBox({
       content: actualMarkers[i]
      ,disableAutoPan: true
      ,maxWidth: 0
      ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-20, -35)
      ,zIndex: 100000
      ,boxStyle: { 
        opacity: 1
       }
      ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
      ,isHidden: false
      ,pane: "floatPane"
      ,enableEventPropagation: false
    });

    infoBoxes[i].open(map, googleMarker);
  }
  setBearings();
}
updateInfoBoxes();
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `.animate()` instead of `.css()` + transitions?  It'll work for all browsers, and will work predictably.

Comment: Fantastic suggestion, thanks so much. Will this have a knock on performance? I'll be using this across multiple platforms and want to make sure the animations are as smooth as possible.

Comment: If you can write an example as an answer I'll select it as best. :)

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle

Comment: @JoelKidd - I'm not aware of any benchmarks measuring jQuery animate vs CSS3 transitions - I would imagine the latter is hands-down better-performing considering it's using native browser code to do the animation instead of DHTML (changing CSS properties via JavaScript in a recursive setTimeout loop), which is what jQuery animate does.  That said, I've never run into problems with performance using animate.  I think you'll be fine.

Comment: @JoelKidd - I'm not going to provide that as an answer, as I'm not sure how well `.animate` works with rotation.  Why don't you try it out, and if it works, provide the answer to your own question?

Answer (score 0):

Real quick example of how to do this. click the red box, and it will rotate to 50deg.

http://jsfiddle.net/hmXGF/

```
.marker{
    transition: ease 5s;
    -webkit-transition: ease 5s;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

make sure you declare a base transform, so it has a value to start from. 
Oh and don't forget all the wonderful prefixes, for the rest of your browser friends. Hope this helps.

Comment: if you want to support ie9 (it supports transforms but not transitions). Look in to using the code from this guy: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/22/jquery-patch-css-transform.html it allows jquery animation of transforms...